# Laravel 5 Environment Detection on Windows 8.1 not working

Tags: development-environment, laravel-5, env

**Now its working just updated to 5.0.6 version.**

```
$ php artisan env
Current application environment: production
```

so duplicated `.env.example` file to `.env.production` but got no luck

So I checked in `Foundation->Bootstrap->DetectEnvironment.php` at line number 18 `$app->environmentFile()`

It always give `.env` instead of `.env.production`

```
try
{
    Dotenv::load($app['path.base'], $app->environmentFile());
}
```

so again duplicated `.env.example` to `.env` 
after this **env variables** are available but at random time sometimes it read and sometimes not. now I am not sure where to look what wrong with process.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

To use Laravel Environment you have to chage `.env.example` to `.env` and change your own configuration in `.env`

Read more about Environment Configuration on [Laravel Doc](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration)

Comment: No idea whats wrong, just updated laravel 5.0.6 and now its working. thanks anyway guys!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need a single `.env` file at your root with your configuration. Change `APP_ENV` to your desired environment.

If you are using `php artisan serve` to run your application remember to stop it and rerun `php artisan serve` command after you change the .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but i was having the same issue today...

It seems the dot-env file is not derived from the application's environment but rather from the `ENVIRONMENT_FILE` environment variable...

```
$ php artisan tinker --env=foo
Psy Shell v0.4.4 (PHP 5.4.39 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> app()
=> <Illuminate\Foundation\Application #000000003700ceef000000004af960b1> {
       configurationIsCached: false,
       environment: "foo",
       environmentFile: ".env",
       isLocal: false,
       ...
```

Even though the environment is 'foo' the `.env.foo` file is not used. So apart from setting the environment you need to set a environment variable as well.

```
$ ENVIRONMENT_FILE=".env.foo" php artisan tinker --env=foo
Psy Shell v0.4.4 (PHP 5.4.39 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> app()
=> <Illuminate\Foundation\Application #00000000570e634e0000000052841910> {
       configurationIsCached: false,
       environment: "foo",
       environmentFile: ".env.foo",
       isLocal: false,
       ...
```

The migration from having multiple environments with each their own config tree (overriding the global one) to basically dropping the concept of environments but instead take/override a bunch of config settings from "the environment" (unix shell env, Apache's SetEnv, dot-env, ...) is still ongoing I guess, leading to this confusing situation.